# Magento 1 custom url rewrite gives 404 issue

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

From the layer navigation, i have a couple of attributes.
After i click my url looks like:

```
brand/brandValue.html?productAttribute=productAttribute1
```

What i want to achieve is to have that url look like

```
brand/brandValue/productAttribute1.html
```

With a `custom` url rewrite, where the:

`requested path : brand/brandValue.html?productAttribute=productAttribute1`

and the

```
target path: brand/brandValue/productAttribute1.html
```

I got my redirect, with the permanent(301) but it redirects you to 404 . How can i achieve this goal ? Thnx